# What is the significance of underflow during parameter update using stochastic gradient descent?

Tags: python, neural-network, gradient-descent

#### Background

I am using scikit-learn's [`MLPRegressor`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neural_network.MLPRegressor.html#sklearn.neural_network.MLPRegressor) to learn a model with the following arguments:

```
hidden_layer_sizes=(16, 16),
learning_rate_init=1e-2,
solver='sgd',
momentum=0.9,
activation='tanh',
learning_rate='constant'
```

I use `partial_fit()` to incrementally fit the model. Occasionally I get a `FloatingPointError` on this line in the `MLPRegressor`'s code:

```
updates = [self.momentum * velocity - self.learning_rate * grad
                   for velocity, grad in zip(self.velocities, grads)]

>>> FloatingPointError: underflow encountered in multiply
```

#### Problem

I am getting an underflow error when the model is calculating how much to update parameters by multiplying learning rate, momentum, velocity, and error gradients.

Does not an underflow mean that the updates are too small? Does it imply the model has reached some local minimum? Should I take this as a hint that:

- I have exhausted my data and training has ended,
- I should up my learning rate to keep updates happening
- Something else?

Comment: try to change your inputs types to `np.float64`

Comment: @DemetryPascal This has actually resolved my issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Underflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_underflow) is happening because the result of that calculation is a number of smaller absolute value than your computer can actually represent in memory.

Underflow is not directly related to the performance of the model (e.g., learning rate or local minimum). Underflow is the interplay between computer software and hardware.

I suggest rescaling the data. For example, batch normalization often stops underflow errors.